# GitHub REST API: Efficiently Fetch Comment Lists from Mutliple Issues

Tags: api, rest, github

I want to use the GitHub REST API to fetch "a list of comments made in repository X since date Y".

GitHub does not appear to have a specific API method designed to do what I want *efficiently*.

The [`repos/comments`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/comments/) method appears to return git commit comments, not GitHub issue comments.

The [`issues/comments` method](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#list-issue-comments) will let me fetch comments made on a *single* issue.

The best I've been able to come up with is querying for issues (which will include PRs) for a date range, and then making a single API call per issue. This means if there's been activity in 20 issues, I'm making 21 API calls (one for the list of issues and then twenty for each issue to get the comments).

This feels inefficient.  Is there a way to get the information I want (all issue comments made on a repository within a date range) using fewer API calls?

Comment: Have you tried the GraphQL API? Being able to describe the data you want is the point of it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Useful information, thank you.  I have lightly investigated the graphql API and wasn't able to figure out a query that would get what I wanted -- it seemed like the structure of the objects led to the same problems as I described above.  However, I'm far from comfortable in a GraphQL world -- if someone had a query that got what I wanted I'd consider it an acceptable answer.